# Blackberry10 cascade qmlRegisterType can not register object

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, qtimer

This is how I registered my timer:

```
qmlRegisterType<QTimer>("bb.Timer", 1, 0, "QTimer");
```

And this is how I'm using it:

```
import bb.Timer 1.0; //error Unknown library 'bb.Timer'

Page {
    Container {

        Button {
            id: playButton
            text: "Play"
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            onClicked: {                   
                    player.play();
            }
            attachedObjects: [
                QTimer  { //error The QTimer component might be an unknown or //custom component. Its properties are not validated.
                    id: mTimer
                    interval: 2000
                    onTimeout: {
                        playButton.text = "new page"                       
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Show your code where you register new type and load qml file, please. Also btw there is already [Timer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html) in `QML`

Comment: I'm kinda new at this I'm new at this... i using momentics ide to program this is how i register my Qtimer                            qmlRegisterType<QTimer>("bb.Timer", 1, 0, "QTimer");                                   and this is how i load my qml file                                         QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);